# Solr - Successful query with numfound > 0 but docs returned are empty?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, solr-query-syntax

I'm pretty new to Solr but something is not working as expected...

I'm searching for documents where the `name = 'the*'`. This query is working since I'm getting a `numFound > 0`. But the docs in the response are empty even though I have set `&fl=*`

I would like to display all the fields available for the documents in the response. (I also tried with `&fl=name` but it doesn't change anything.

**My query:**

> `http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select
>   q=name%3Athe*&rows=5&fl=*&wt=json&indent=true`

**The response:**

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "name:the*",
      "indent": "true",
      "fl": "*",
      "rows": "5",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1409803190693"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 257052,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Would need to see your field definitions to know, but for a shot in the dark:  You may not be storing any fields.  A field with `indexed=true` can be searched, a field with `stored=true` can be retrieved.  See [Solr's common field options](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options).

Comment: yes, looks like none of the field is stored.

Comment: @femtoRgon Thank you for your help, but I checked my schema.xml and I found this for the name field: `<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`. Can this issue come from when the index was made? I didn't create the index so maybe the fields weren't stored and that's why I can't access it now?

Comment: @Romain - It would definitely take affect only when the index was created.  To fix that, the index would need to be recreated with the correct fields being stored.

Comment: @femtoRgon - I understand now, thanks for the explanation. Now I'm wondering what can be the purpose of such an index (with 0 field stored?), I'm not sure to understand the point of this since nothing can be displayed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that when the index was created the fields were not `stored` in the `schema.xml` file so I couldn't access them after (even with the `stored` attribut set to `true`).

Comment: Same problem I faced but little different. I have numFound=29 but I set the start=40 :(